# how to unit test subscription to a BehaviourSubject in angular

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I have a `UserManagementService` which exposes an `Observable` of a `BehaviourSubject`.

```
this.userSignInState$ = this.signInStateSubject.asObservable();
```

I subscribe to `userSignInState` in a `nav` component.

```
constructor(public userManagementService: UserManagementService, private fb:FormBuilder, private helper:HelperService) {
    this.userSignInStateSubscription = this.userManagementService.userSignInState$.subscribe(
          (result:Result)=> {
            console.log("In nav - result from user signin state ",result);
            let subscribed:UserSigninState = result.additionalInfo;
            console.log("new user signin state received:", subscribed);
            this.userLoggedIn = subscribed.isSignedIn;
            if(subscribed.isSignedIn && subscribed['additional-info'] !== ''){
              this.profile = JSON.parse(subscribed['additional-info']) as UserProfileAPI
            }
            if(!subscribed.isSignedIn && subscribed['additional-info'] !== ''){
            //  let error:ServerResponseAPI = JSON.parse(subscribed['additional-info']) as ServerResponseAPI
              //let errorMessage:string = this.helper.userFriendlyErrorMessage(error);
              this.navEvent.emit(new NavContext(subscribed['additional-info']));
            }
          },
        (error:ServerResponseAPI)=>{
            console.log("got error from the Observable: ",error);

           let errorMessage:string = this.helper.userFriendlyErrorMessage(error);
           this.navEvent.emit(new NavContext(errorMessage));
    //       this.userloggedIn =false;
      },
      ()=>{ //observable complete
        console.log("observable completed")
        //this.userloggedIn =false;
      });
  }
```

I want to unit test `nav`. The `spec` should test that the `component` subscribes to `userSignInState$` and handles `Result` correctly. How do I do this? As this is a unit test, I don't want to use the real `UserManagementService`

I wrote the following spec

```
fit('should subscribe to user sign in state observable',()=>{
    let userManagementService = TestBed.get(UserManagementService);
    let navComponent:NavComponentComponent = component;
    console.log('component is ',navComponent);
    navComponent.userLoggedIn = false;
    let dummyUserProfile = new UserProfileAPI(new User('fn','ln','test@test.com'));
    userManagementService.signInStateSubject.next(new Result('success',(new UserSigninState(true,JSON.stringify(dummyUserProfile ))).toString));
    expect(navComponent.userLoggedIn).toBe(true)
  });
```

but I got error `Expected undefined to be true.`

I don't understand why `userLoggedIn` is undefined. I have declared it in the `nav` class

```
export class NavComponentComponent implements OnInit  {

  userLoggedIn:boolean;
...
}
```

I set it in `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit(){

    this.userLoggedIn = false;
  ...
}
```

I also moved the subscription logic to `ngOnInit` but that doesn't work either and gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the way I was creating `Result`. I should have not used `.toString` with `userSignInState`. From another question I posted in `SO`, "reference to .toString without () is just a reference to that function, so if you log that you get the code for that function." Also, "toString() will not work as userSignInState doesn't have a meanigful string representation and is defaulting to [object Object]". I removed `toString` and the code worked as `additional-info` is of type `any`